# How much will it hurt my career progression to take ~1 month of medical leave 3 months into a new job?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, human-resources, health

I just accepted a job offer as a software engineer at a medium-size company which is known for being very selective with hiring (more difficult to get into than the average FAANG company) and having very high standards for their engineers. I'm a bit stressed, because I have a surgery scheduled in 4 months, which will require me to take about a month off of work.

It's not a life-saving surgery, but will dramatically improve my quality of life. I could potentially reschedule it, but that would cost me a lot of money, and the next available date is too far into the future for me to be comfortable with.

My main concern is that this will cause me to start off on the wrong foot with the company, and jeopardize my position there since I would be taking the time off before establishing myself there.

Is there anything I should do about this? Would it make sense to ask for input from HR or my new manager on how much trouble this would cause? What should I be taking into account when assessing the potential career impact of this decision? The surgery is important to me, but I'd rather postpone the surgery than potentially get fired.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I mentioned it briefly to my third-party recruiter and internal recruiter (who joined the company very recently, I was his first hire), but didn't get a solid answer other than "it's probably fine, do whatever is best for you". I feel as though they wouldn't tell me to postpone the surgery, as it would be unprofessional for them to do so.

Comment: Question - how much of the 'Month off' is actually required? e.g. say you were doing some Back surgery and the Doctors said 'A Month off for recovery' - that might be the standard answer for a job with a physical component, whereas being a Software engineer - you might have some lee-way.

Comment: Please add a location tag. Acceptability and local laws vary greatly from country to country.

Comment: How having to take a medical leave will have you fired? I cannot connect the dots. Who told you that only 'established' employees can take medical leaves? Prioritizing your work over your health is the recipe for personal destruction and leaving you unable to work. Take care of yourself. And keep in mind there are plenty of opportunities out there.

Comment: @CapBarracudas My concern is not that I'll be fired for taking the leave. My concern is that it would set back my progression, and, perhaps, after about a year they'll be unsatisfied with my overall performance and I'll be wishing I hadn't taken the time off. I think this is unlikely, but I'm just trying to plan ahead and consider all possible ways this could go.

Comment: It will set you back by however long you are out. They should be able to adjust their expectations for that.

Comment: You might want to add a country tag to your question.

Comment: "My concern is that it would set back my progression, and, perhaps, after about a year they'll be unsatisfied with my overall performance and I'll be wishing I hadn't taken the time off." - When you return after your medical leave, work hard, if the difference between determining you are not a good fit after a year is due to a month off your probably at the wrong company.

Answer (score 5):

> My main concern is that this will cause me to start off on the wrong foot with the company, and jeopardize my position there since I would be taking the time off before establishing myself there.

It makes sense to be concerned about taking that much time off so early in your job tenure. In some companies you would still be in "onboarding mode". Being out that long is likely something that needs to be planned and mitigated.

> Is there anything I should do about this?

You should discuss this with your boss now. They may want to alter training and/or project plans to account for your absence. The sooner they can do this, the less the impact. Bosses don't like surprises.

> Would it make sense to ask for input from HR or my new manager on how much trouble this would cause?

Yes. Input from your manager might alleviate your concern or help you make whatever decisions you need to make.

If you need input regarding your insurance coverage or your rights regarding time off, talk with HR.

> What should I be taking into account when assessing the potential career impact of this decision?

As with all decisions, get all the information you can before deciding.

Most likely, taking this time off will be fine - certainly in the long term, and likely even in the short term. Still, your manager will appreciate knowing about it as soon as possible so that they can alter their plans as needed.

Talk to them now. Don't wait.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you were hired right now specifically because there's a deadline they needed your help to meet, it may be frustrating but shouldn't be a long-term problem.

However: How much of that time needs to be spent not working? Given that everyone understands remote work better than a few years ago, and given your profession, you might be telecommuting from your sick room in a much shorter time than that. Heck, I'd be *begging* to be allowed to do that; being pinned in place not being allowed to do anything would drive me batty(er) and I'd welcome the distraction!
.

Comment: I've let my new employer know about a planned vacation for 2 weeks over Christimas when I was hired at the end of November. We figured something out and there were no issues. Need to let them know ASAP **after** signing the contract...

Answer (score 1):

Taking care of your health has much more significance for your future career prospects than having a month-long break in my opinion.

Communicate this to your manager as soon as possible so they can factor in your leave into their plans. Also, look for the ways to minimize the impact of your leave on your workplace. Working from home is a good option to start earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The size and stability of the company is likely to influence attitudes. A large company that plans it's workforce ahead won't miss you for a month, and won't miss the cost of your salary.

A small company that's desperately needed a new member of staff for some time, would probably be in uproar.

The importance of the surgery, and the long-term implications for your health at work, will also probably influence attitudes. Employers are probably more sympathetic to a new employee going off for knee surgery, than they are to either a cosmetic hair transplant, or cancer.

There's one obvious question, which is why you changed jobs so near to such an event? Or was it compulsory due to circumstances?

It's unclear overall how urgent or important you consider the surgery to be.

There may be local laws that protect you from being fired in these circumstances. I can't imagine it affecting career progression, from the year mark onwards. A month's leave for legitimate surgery would likely have been forgotten by then, even if it was inconvenient at the time.

The best thing to do is to ensure you have a conversation as soon as possible about booking the time off. 3 months' notice is generally ample, and it's not soon as to disrupt usual induction arrangements in a new job, or so soon that it would have made sense to delay the start date until afterwards.

If you've genuinely mentioned the need for time off earlier in the recruitment process, then it's reasonable to approach your manager (or HR) in the tone of merely formalising in the calendar what you've already notified.

It's reasonable to take this approach even if you know the information wasn't, in fact, relayed from the person you informed. An absence of significant concern and internal fuss about such medical leave may be a sign of a responsible employer.

However it may be a harder conversation to have if you didn't mention it earlier at an appropriate time (such as on a form asking whether you had any fixtures in your own calendar like holidays). In this situation, it might be better to open the conversation in the tone of *asking permission* to take time off, and justify it on the basis that you've tried to rearrange the surgery for the future but have found that it would be unreasonably delayed. They may have no real grounds to refuse, but it avoids presenting the need for imminent leave as an accomplished fact, and it avoids suggesting that it was already a fixture since it can in theory be rearranged.

Comment: Why should cancer be treated similarly to a cosmetic hair transplant?

Comment: @PiotrGolacki, because the hair transplant would be considered a trivial reason for such significant leave, whereas the cancer could spell long-term sickliness (and more such absence). I certainly don't want to suggest these are the correct perspectives on the matter, only that they are the perspectives that an employer might well develop.